# Why org-mode related settings aren't applied on desktop.el restored .org files?

Tags: org-mode, desktop

When my emacs start, previously visited buffers/files are restored with desktop.el. So far so good.

But my settings related to org-mode files are somehow not applied.

If I open a new org file or if I manually load `org-mode` on a restored org file then my settings are applied.

Here is a minimal reproducible config :

.emacs :

```lisp
(setq company-backends '(company-ac-php-backend
                         company-lsp
                         company-bbdb
                         company-semantic
                         company-clang
                         company-cmake
                         company-capf
                         company-files
                         (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
                         company-oddmuse
                         company-dabbrev))

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auto-install/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp_files/")

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

(gcmh-mode 1)

(require 'org)
(org-babel-load-file "~/.emacs.d/config.org")
```

The config.el compiled with org-babel :

```lisp
;; Persistence stuff
(setq desktop-save 'ask)
(push '(name . nil) frameset-filter-alist)

(setq desktop-globals-to-save
      (append '((extended-command-history . 100)
                (command-history          . 100)
                (file-name-history        . 100)
                (grep-history             . 50)
                (compile-history          . 40)
                (minibuffer-history       . 100)
                (query-replace-history    . 100)
                (read-expression-history  . 100)
                (regexp-history           . 100)
                (regexp-search-ring       . 100)
                (search-ring              . 100)
                (shell-command-history    . 100)
                tags-file-name
                register-alist)))

(desktop-save-mode 1)
(desktop-read)

(setq desktop-load-locked-desktop 'ask)


;; org-mode stuff
(require 'org-bullets)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
(setq org-bullets-face-name (quote org-bullet-face))
(setq org-bullets-bullet-list '("➊" "➋" "❸" "4" "5" "⑥" "⑦" "8" "9" "◯" "⚪" "⚫" "⚬" "❍" "￮" "⊙" "⊚" "⊛" "∙" "∘"))

(setq org-ellipsis " ⤵")
```

On desktop restored org files, org-bullets-mode is not active and `org-ellipsis` is still '...' (but weirdly `describe-variable` says the value is " ⤵").

This situation is very troublesome, because I have to manually load `org-mode` on **every** restored org buffers to have my settings applied to them !

What is going on ?

> GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.30,  cairo version 1.16.0) of 2021-11-27, modified by Debian

> Org mode version 9.5.3 (9.5.3-g69c588 @ /home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.5.3/)

Comment: Maybe you can move `config.el` to `.emacs` and remove `org-babel-load-file` to check if it takes effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, things are working now, don't bother.

I'm not sure I remember exactly what I did (sorry, I should have posted right away), but I, at least :

- Removed my desktop file (Yes, sad)
- Removed the `(desktop-read)` instruction (redundant with `(desktop-save-mode 1)`)